# Merging the column names based on the values to create another column

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

I have a movies dataset containing various movie genres and whether the movie belongs to that genre or not. E.g.

```
Index Biography Comedy  Crime   Documentary Drama   Family  Fantasy
0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
2   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
3   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
5   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
6   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

I would like to get a new column having the movie genres names separated by a space or comma if the movie belongs to that genre like

```
Index  New column
0    Comedy Drama Family
1    Comedy Family
2    Drama
3    Comedy
4    Comedy Drama
5    Crime Drama
```

Please share the code in R or Python.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are satisfied with an answer, don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/295067) it - click on the check mark (✓) beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Maybe they just like the question

Answer (score 2):

With matrix multiplication in Python:

```
df.dot(df.columns + " ")
```

to get

```
Index
0    Comedy Drama Family
1          Comedy Family
2                  Drama
3                 Comedy
4           Comedy Drama
5            Crime Drama
6                 Comedy
```

---

to make it more generic:

```
sep = ", "
df.dot(df.columns + sep).str.rstrip(sep)
```

i.e., add the separator to column names, perform the matrix-vector multiplication and then right strip the separator at the end.

Comment: This is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
  apply(1, function(x){which(x == 1)}) %>% 
  lapply(function(x){
    paste(names(x), collapse = " ")
    }) %>%
  unlist() -> df$your_new_column
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
my.movies <- read.table(text = 'Index Biography Comedy  Crime   Documentary Drama   Family  Fantasy
0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
2   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
3   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
5   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
6   0   1   0   0   0   0   0', header = T)
library(tidyverse)
my.movies %>%
  pivot_longer(!Index, names_to = 'genre') %>%
  filter(value !=0) %>%
  group_by(Index) %>%
  summarise(genre = toString(genre))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   Index genre                
#>   <int> <chr>                
#> 1     0 Comedy, Drama, Family
#> 2     1 Comedy, Family       
#> 3     2 Drama                
#> 4     3 Comedy               
#> 5     4 Comedy, Drama        
#> 6     5 Crime, Drama         
#> 7     6 Comedy
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Base R -

```
df$new_col <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(names(x)[x == 1], collapse = ' '))
```

`dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Index) %>%
  summarise(new_col = paste0(names(.[-1])[cur_data() == 1], collapse = ' '))

#  Index new_col            
#  <int> <chr>              
#1     0 Comedy Drama Family
#2     1 Comedy Family      
#3     2 Drama              
#4     3 Comedy             
#5     4 Comedy Drama       
#6     5 Crime Drama        
#7     6 Comedy
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Index = 0:6, Biography = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), Comedy = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Crime = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Documentary = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), Drama = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Family = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fantasy = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic python code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

def check_genre(row):
    s = ""
    if row['biography'] == 1:
        s = s + ' biography'
    if row['comedy'] == 1:
        s = s + ' comedy'
    if row['crime'] == 1:
        s = s + ' crime'
    if row['Documentary'] == 1:
        s = s + ' Documentary'
    if row['Drama'] == 1:
        s = s + ' Drama'
    if row['Family'] == 1:
        s = s + ' Family'
    if row['Fantasy'] == 1:
        s = s + ' Fantasy'

    return s

df['genre'] = df.apply(lambda row: check_genre(row), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

In pandas, you can extract index values for row values that are equal to 1 and then convert them to a string:

```py
df.apply(lambda row: " ".join(row[row == 1].index), axis=1)

# Index
# 0    Comedy Drama Family
# 1          Comedy Family
# 2                  Drama
# 3                 Comedy
# 4           Comedy Drama
# 5            Crime Drama
# 6                 Comedy
```

Answer (score 0):

Post the response in R/dplyr

if "main_df" is your DataFrame as per first image.
Make the dataframe longer so that all the genre columns are in tidy format.
`group_by` based on the index since that's per movie and collapse the genre column using `paste`

```
main_df%>%
  pivot_longer(cols=-index)%>%
  filter(value>0)%>% # filter where movie is part of the genre i.e 1
  group_by(index)%>%
  mutate(new_genre = paste(name,collapse = ","))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  distinct(index,new_genre)-> main_df2

# if you want to merge back to the original data frame use left_join

left_join(main_df, main_df2,by="index")
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduces to an

- unstack
- filter
- aggregate

```
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Index Biography Comedy  Crime   Documentary Drama   Family  Fantasy
0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
2   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
3   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
5   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
6   0   1   0   0   0   0   0"""), sep="\s+").set_index("Index")

df.unstack().to_frame().loc[lambda d: d[0].eq(1)].reset_index().groupby("Index").agg({"level_0":" ".join})
```

| Index | level_0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Comedy Drama Family |
| 1 | Comedy Family |
| 2 | Drama |
| 3 | Comedy |
| 4 | Comedy Drama |
| 5 | Crime Drama |
| 6 | Comedy |